# Как передать сигнал из одного класса в другой?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

Имеется код, в котором необходимо, чтобы список из `Start_window` отобразился в текущем окне. Понимаю, что это необходимо сделать сигналами, но не понимаю как.

```
import openpyxl
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

class readFromXL(QListWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


class Start_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(500, 500)   # Внешний вид окна
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Import to the Database')
        self.setWindowIcon((QIcon('icons/iconTitle')))

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Готово')  # Статус

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('icons/iconExit.png'), 'Выход', self)     # Меню: выход
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        importAction = QAction(QIcon('icons/iconImport.png'),'Импорт..', self)  # Меню: импорт
        importAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        importAction.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()    # Меню
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        fileMenu.addAction(importAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.show()

    def center(self):   # Отцентровка окна
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def showDialog(self):   # Выбор файла
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home', '*.xls*')[0]
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
        sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Start_window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

Сигналы здесь еще не нужны.
Как вариант посмотрите пример ниже:

```
import openpyxl
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

class readFromXL(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #self.initUI()        # ??

    def Clicked(self, item):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "ListWidget", "Вы кликнули: "+item.text())

class Start_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(grid)

        self.readXL = readFromXL()

        self.initUI()

        grid.addWidget(self.readXL, 0, 0)

    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(500, 500)                         # Внешний вид окна
        #self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Import to the Database')
        #self.setWindowIcon((QIcon('icons/iconTitle')))
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('E:/_Qt/img/qt-logo.png'))      

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Готово')        # Статус

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('icons/iconExit.png'), 'Выход', self)       # Меню: выход
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        importAction = QAction(QIcon('icons/iconImport.png'),'Импорт..', self) # Меню: импорт
        importAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+I')
        importAction.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()             # Меню
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('Файл')
        fileMenu.addAction(importAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.show()

    def center(self):                        # Отцентровка окна
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def showDialog(self):                    # Выбор файла
        #fname  = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home', '*.xls*')[0]
        fname  = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '.', '*.xls*')[0]
        wb     = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
        sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()

        self.readXL.addItems(sheets)
        self.readXL.itemClicked.connect(self.readXL.Clicked)     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Start_window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]